# jQuery - Selecting the value of a span via classname

Tags: jquery, html, classname

I want to get the value of a span by knowing only the class name. In the document there is only one span with that class. I tried like this:

```
$('span.foo').text();
```

But it doesn't return anything. How can I do that?

Comment: Make a JSFiddle plz, http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: It should work. Can you post your HTML?

Comment: Your code is an expression statement. It does return a value, but you're not assigning it to anything. If you want the value, assign the expression to a variable/argument/property. For instance: `var text = $('span.foo').text();`

Answer (score 2):

[demo](http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/e9231.php)

works fine for me

```
<span class="foo"> 
bar 
</span> 
<script> 
alert($('span.foo').text()); 
</script>
```